# How to ensure MPI asynchronous calls are executed in parallel?

Tags: c++, multithreading, asynchronous, mpi

I have a program that I am trying to accelerate, but I am not sure that the MPI asynchronous communication is behaving in the way I expect. I expect that a thread is created which performs the communication while the original thread can continue computation in parallel. How can I ensure the program executes this way?

The base program issues an `Allgather` every `x` iterations containing `x` iterations worth of future data. Any iteration only uses data produced `x` iterations ago. My idea was that instead of batching iterations of data together into a blocking `Allgather` (what the base program already does), I could issue an asynchronous `Iallgather` after every iteration and just check that the data has arrived `x` iterations from now. The program is ~90% computation so I thought this presented ample opportunity to hide the latencies of the communication. Unfortunately, the program is much slower now than before I started on it. The system has a message passing latency which is much smaller than the time it takes to perform `x` iterations of code for messages of this size.

I modified my code to try and debug a bit. I had 2 ideas about what could be causing the problem:

1. The asynchronous communication is just slower for some reason
2. The communication and computation are not being performed in parallel

To test (1), I turned all of the `Iallgather`s into `Allgather`s - the results were identical. This led me to believe that my `Iallgather`s were not being performed in parallel.

To test (2), I am not at all sure I did this right. I thought that calling `MPI_Wait(&my_handle, ...)` might force the calling thread to progress the transmission so I did something like this.

```
MPI_Iallgather(send_data, send_data_size, ..., &handle);
#pragma omp task
{
    MPI_Wait(&handle, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
}
```

This may be the wrong approach, maybe the thread that issues the `Iallgather` has to perform it.

In summary: I want computation to continue while an `Iallgather` or any asynchronous communication call is being performed in parallel. How do I ensure that these are being performed as I expect? Is there a chance that it is being performed in parallel and the performance is garbage? I would expect that I would at least see a difference in execution time when switching `Iallgather` to `Allgather` in my code.

I realize that some answers to this question are likely to be iplementation dependent so I'm using openMPI 5.0.0a1.

Comment: The MPI standard does not mandate a progress thread, so nothing **might** happen after `MPI_Iallgather()` until you `MPI_Wait()` (or `MPI_Test()` and friends). If an OpenMP region can be overlapped with the communication, a simple trick is to `MPI_Allgather()` in a `#pragma omp master` section, and use dynamic load balancing. Also, make sure you `MPI_Init_thread()` with the appropriate thread support level.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback! I ended up going with using an `MPI_Allgather()` inside an OpenMP pragma. Turns out the boost mpi library wasn't properly doing `MPI_Init_thread()` in the way i thought it was. Regardless, I get different results now!